# Jinja2 returning empty string for item that exists from yaml import

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I'm bringing in yaml and using it to populate some jinja templates, I've simplified everything into this demo below, copy paste and it should run. Jinja is not finding the `a['ports']['b']['vmtype']` objects even though they appear to be a perfectly fine dict in python debug.

Python

```py
    from jinja2 import Template
    from yaml import safe_load
    
    with open('demo.jinja', 'r') as templatefile:
        template = Template(templatefile.read())
    
    with open("demo.yaml", 'r') as stream:
        configs = safe_load(stream)
    
    for config in configs:
        output = template.render(configs[config])
        print(output)
```

YAML

```yaml
---
  a:
    name: foo
    example: helloworld
    ports:
      a:
      b:
        vmtype: aa
      c:
        vmtype: bb
      d:
        vmtype: cc
```

Jinja

```
{{ name }}
Things
{% for port in ports %}
    {% if 'vmtype' in port %}
    this worked "{{ port }}"
    this worked "{{ port.vmtype }}"
    {%- else -%}
    this didn't work "{{  port  }}"
    this didn't work "{{  port.vmtype  }}"
    {%- endif -%}
{% endfor %}
end things
{{ example }}
```

This only outputs the `this didn't work` lines for all of the port objects in the loop and they do not contain the vmtype strings.

Libraries used: PyYaml and Jinja2

Comment: you're iterating only over the keys, not the config values (which is a dict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your port config is a dict

You need traverse it like this

```
{{ name }}
Things
{% for port, data in ports.items() %}
    {% if data.vmtype %}
      this worked "{{ port }}"
      this worked "{{ data.vmtype }}"
    {% else %}
      this didn't work "{{  port  }}"
      this didn't work "{{  data.vmtype  }}"
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
end things
{{ example }}

Reference https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#list-of-control-structures
```